# Checking user type using hasattr()

Tags: python, django

Some of my users are students. When a user creates a student profile the StudentProfile class is instantiated:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True)
    …
```

How can I check if a user is a student?

```
hasattr(request.user, 'StudentProfile')
```

returns False even when the logged-in user has an associated StudentProfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there - you just need to use lowercase `studentprofile` instead of `StudentProfile`:

```
hasattr(request.user, 'studentprofile')
```

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield):

> If you do not specify the `related_name` argument for the `OneToOneField`, Django will use the lower-case name of the current model as default value.